# How to create a regex from the keys of a JS object?

Tags: javascript, regex

From the `DOCUMENT_FILE_TYPES` object, how can I convert to below (separate the object keys by pipe)

```
msword|vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

**End result**

```
acceptFileTypes = /(\.|\/)(msword|vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)$/i;
```

**From**

```
var DOCUMENT_FILE_TYPES = {
    "application/msword": "doc", 
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document": "docx",
}
```

Comment: what's the question here?

Comment: The question is how to create the regex from the object.

Answer (score 0):

Get the keys from the object:

```
var keys = Object.keys(DOCUMENT_FILE_TYPES);
```

Remove the `application/`:

```
var apps = keys . map(function(key) {
  return key.replace(/^application\//, ''); 
})
```

Join them together with the pipe, inside grouping parentheses:

```
var app_group = '(' + apps.join('|') + ')';
```

Then create your regexp:

```
var acceptFileTypes = new Regexp('(\\.|\\/)' + app_group + '$', 'i');
```